# Add role based authentication using next-auth in NextJS

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, next-auth

I was implementing a role based authentication using **next-auth v4** using **CognitoProvider** which I modified to add a role but the role attribute is not passed in the final session json

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";

function CognitoProvider(options) {
  return {
    id: "cognito",
    name: "Cognito",
    type: "oauth",
    wellKnown: `${options.issuer}/.well-known/openid-configuration`,
    idToken: true,
    profile(profile) {
      console.log(profile);
      return {
        id: profile.sub,
        name: profile.name,
        email: profile.email,
        image: profile.picture,
        role: profile["cognito:groups"],
      };
    },
    options,
  };
}

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CognitoProvider({
      clientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: process.env.COGNITO_DOAMIN,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    session: (props) => {
      console.log(props);
      return props.session;
    },
  },
});
```

### Below is the console log of profile object

[image]

```js
role: profile["cognito:groups"]
```

### Actual Object

[image]

**I have added a user to admin group and wanted him to access a specific route in my NextJS app.**

*Any help would be appreciated.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure the [`jwt`](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#jwt-callback) and [`session`](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#session-callback) callbacks to include more data in the session.

From Next-Auth docs:

> If you want to make something available you added to the token [...] via the `jwt()` callback, you have to explicitly forward it here [the `session()` callback] to make it available to the client.

To add the user's role:

```js
export default NextAuth({
  // ...
  callbacks: {
    jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
        if (account) {
            // modify token
            token.role = profile.role;
        }

        return token;
    },

    session({ session, token }) {
      // Send properties to the client

      if (session.user) {
        // modify session
        session.user.roles = token.role;
      }

      return session;
    },
  },
});
```

Then in your route, you would get the user's role from the [session](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#getsession) `session.user.role`

Comment: in the session callback token is undefined along with the user attributes  https://i.ibb.co/rMbNbM7/2022-12-28-00-27-56-nextauth-js-streamify-Visual-Studio-Code.png

Comment: Updated code https://gist.github.com/arihant-jain-09/d2e9c4b0c7b0c0d0f96ea2e27b9338aa

Comment: @ArihantJain sorry I made a mistake. In the `jwt` callback, you need to `return token`

Comment: updated code https://gist.github.com/arihant-jain-09/d2e9c4b0c7b0c0d0f96ea2e27b9338aa token.role = profile["cognito:groups"];  worked!